# While-Loop completion issue and final value calculations

Tags: java, javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm having trouble with my looped statement and can't get it to properly execute without it reverting to the original looped condition. Also if I want my final output to include pricing values for the total number of products bought how would I achieve this?

**FINAL OUTPUT DESIRED: Customer purchases all 9 items**

> Please enter your name: John Smith
>
> GRAPEFRUIT PRODUCT
>
> 1. gPod shuffle   $49
> 2. gPod Touch $299
> 3. gPad Mini  $329
> 4. gPad 2 $399
> 5. gPhone $199
> 6. gMac           $1299
> 7. MacNovel Pro   $1199
> 8. MacNovel Air   $999
> 9. MiniMac    $599
> 10. Complete my order
>
> Please select an item from the menu above: 5
>
> Please select another item from the menu above: 2
>
> Please select another item from the menu above: 7
>
> Please select another item from the menu above: 9
>
> Please select another item from the menu above: 3
>
> Please select another item from the menu above: 4
>
> Please select another item from the menu above: 6
>
> Please select another item from the menu above: 1
>
> Please select another item from the menu above: 8
>
> Please select another item from the menu above: 10   Thank you for
>   ordering with Grapefruit Company, John Smith
>
> Total items ordered: 9
>
> Price of items ordered: $5371
>
> Sales tax: $349.115
>
> Total amount due: $5720.115

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Declare Variables
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String CustomerName;
        int gpodShuffle = 1;
        int gpodTouch = 2;
        int gpadMini = 3; 
        int gpadTwo = 4;
        int gphone = 5;
        int gmac = 6;
        int macnovelPro = 7;
        int macnovelAir = 8;
        int miniMac = 9;
        int nNumber = 0;
        int nProducts = 0;
        int nTotal = 0;

        //Declare Constants 
        final int SENTINEL = 10;
        final double SALES_TAX = 6.5;
        final int GPOD_SHUFFLE = 49;
        final int GPOD_TOUCH = 299;
        final int GPAD_MINI = 329;
        final int GPAD_TWO = 399;
        final int GPHONE = 199;
        final int GMAC = 1299;
        final int MAC_NOVELPRO = 1199;
        final int MAC_NOVELAIR = 999;
        final int MINI_MAC = 599;

        //Prompt user to enter name
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");

        //Enter user name
        CustomerName = input.nextLine();

        //Print Blank Line 
        System.out.println("");

        //Begin Product Listing
        System.out.println("GRAPEFRUIT PRODUCT:");

        System.out.println("1. gPod shuffle $49");

        System.out.println("2. gPod Touch   $299");

        System.out.println("3. gPad Mini    $329");

        System.out.println("4. gPad 2       $399");

        System.out.println("5. gPhone       $199");

        System.out.println("6. gMac         $1299");

        System.out.println("7. MacNovel Pro $1199");

        System.out.println("8. MacNovel Air $999");

        System.out.println("9. MiniMac      $599");

        System.out.println("10. Complete my order");

        //Keep reading until the input is 10
        while (nNumber != SENTINEL) {
            //Calculate entered items
            nTotal = nTotal + nNumber;

            nProducts++;

        System.out.println("\nPlease select an item from the menu above: ");

        //Read number entered by the user
        nNumber = input.nextInt();

        if (nNumber == SENTINEL) 
        System.out.println("Thank you for ordering with Grapefruit Company, " + CustomerName);
        else if  (nNumber != SENTINEL) 
        System.out.println("Please select another item from the menu above: ");
        } //End Loop



        //Process selections entered by the user

            //Increment count 


            //Print blank line to screen
            System.out.println("");

            //Total amount of product ordered
            System.out.println("Total items ordered: ");

            //Total price of items ordered
            System.out.println("Price of items ordered: ");

            //Sales tax associated with the purchase
            System.out.println("Sales tax: " + SALES_TAX);

            //Total amount due by the customer to Grapefruit Co. 
            System.out.println("Total amount due: ");


      }

    }
```

Comment: I am not a Java Coder but it doesn't look like you are spitting out any numbers at the end with your strings?  have you not finished coding this yet?  what have you tried?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting when you try to execute this code?  what are the results?

Comment: No, that was incomplete code. The answer provided helped me cure the issue I was receiving, but now I cannot figure out how to add multiple variables within the same string without concatenating them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really crying out for some sort of class to be added to hold these items so you can iterate through these easily.

Nevertheless what you could do in this occassion:

- Hold the prices of the items in an array.

  ```
  int [] itemPrices = {49,299,329,399,199,1299,1199,999,599};
  ```
- Update your print statements

  ```
  System.out.println("1. gPod shuffle $" + prices[0]);

  System.out.println("2. gPod Touch   $" + prices[1]);

  System.out.println("3. gPad Mini    $" + prices[2]);

  System.out.println("4. gPad 2       $" + prices[3]);

  System.out.println("5. gPhone       $" + prices[4]);

  System.out.println("6. gMac         $" + prices[5]);

  System.out.println("7. MacNovel Pro $" + prices[6]);

  System.out.println("8. MacNovel Air $" + prices[7]);

  System.out.println("9. MiniMac      $" + prices[8]);
  ```
- Update the while loop to reference these item prices

  ```
  // Keep reading until the input is 10
  while (nNumber != SENTINEL) 
  {

      System.out.println("\nPlease select an item from the menu above: ");

      // Read number entered by the user
      nNumber = input.nextInt();

      if (nNumber == SENTINEL) 
      {   
          System.out.println("Thank you for ordering with Grapefruit Company, " + CustomerName);
          // The user's just entered the value held for SENTINEL - leave the while loop.
          break;
      } 

      // Calculate the total price.
      nTotal = nTotal + prices[nNumber-1];


      // Increment the total number of products entered.
      nProducts++;
  }
  ```
- Update your final print statements:

  ```
      //Total amount of product ordered
      System.out.println("Total items ordered: " + nProducts);

      //Total price of items ordered
      System.out.println("Price of items ordered: "+nTotal);

      //Sales tax associated with the purchase
      System.out.println("Sales tax: " + SALES_TAX);
  ```

I'll leave you to work out how to get the total amount due :)

Comment: That worked great, thank you! The only issue I'm still running into is how to change the question from "please select an item from the menu above:" to "please select **another** item from the menu above:" in the loop statement.

Comment: place System.out.println("\nPlease select an item from the menu above: "); before the while statement. Then place  System.out.println("\nPlease select another item from the menu above: "); after nProducts++

Comment: System.out.println("Total amount due: " + (SALES_TAX * nTotal) + nTotal ); results in a concatenation of the variables and not a final total answer. This is what I'm trying to input but it puts out the sales tax applicable plus the total price of the products onto the end of the number.

Comment: System.out.println("Total amount due: $" + (SALES_TAX * nTotal + nTotal)); re-did it and it's operational now. Thanks again, friend.

Comment: no problem, as I said in my other answer though - you should review the calculation your doing when calculating the total amount due, this doesn't seem entirely correct.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue with this concatenation you're experiencing:

```
System.out.println("Total amount due: " + ((SALES_TAX * nTotal) + nTotal));
```

This will mean the full calculation is performed before converting it to a string.

**BUT** the maths behind this is wrong, instead do something like the following:

```
// Calculate the amount of tax.
double salesTax = (SALES_TAX/100) * nTotal;
System.out.println("Sales tax: " + salesTax);
```

you should then do:

```
//Total amount due by the customer to Grapefruit Co. 
System.out.println("Total amount due: " + (salesTax + nTotal));
```